# Pointer in C++ Same variable have two different address

Tags: c++, pointers

Normally with this code we should get the same address of the pointer :
if we have such a code normally , `i` and `&i` point to the same address

```
int *i=NULL;
int k=5;
i=&k;
printf("%p %p",&i,i);
```

here is the result of `printf` (only the last digit is different): `0x7fff5fbff8b8 0x7fff5fbff8b4`

can any one please explain me why ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because they are not the same. `i` is a pointer which contains the address of the variable `k`, `&i` is a pointer which contains the address of the variable `i`.

Comment: @Zaibis It is. It's like the number `42` is a constant, but also an `int`. Quoting from C++11 §5.3.1:  The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand.

Comment: @Yu Hao, well but the C standard says a bit different about it ;) Quoting from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 6.5.3.2 `3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’.` It says the return type is of pointer type, what doesn't mean it is a pointer at all, because `int foo(void){return 5;}` has a result of type `int`, but you cant say `foo()` is an itneger ;D

Comment: @Zaibis It's similar in C. Your quoted standard has nothing to do with function return type. By **result**, as another example, the result of `1 + 2` has a type of `int`. I think what you mean is that `&i` is not a pointer **variable**, but my point is it's still a pointer.

Comment: `Apointer type may be derived from a function type, an object type, or an incomplete
type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value
provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from
the referenced type T is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a
pointer type from a referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’.` hm ohkay.... you bet me.... but any way it doesn't says its correct ^^

Answer (score 3):

`i` is a pointer points to an integer. `i`'s value is an address(the address of `k`).

`&i` is `i`'s address.

You just output two different addresses.

You can do this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
   int *i=NULL;
   int k=5;
   i=&k;
   int** j = &i;
   printf("%p %p %p",&i,i,j);
}
```

You can get the output:

```
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$ r
0xbfc8a1a8 0xbfc8a1a4 0xbfc8a1a8
```

See the first address is the same as the third. Because `j`'s value is `i`'s address.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation :) appreciate it :)