# A pointer holding 2 memory locations?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does a pointer hold two memory locations? What is the use case for the 2nd memory location?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    string animal;
    string *rabbit = &animal;
    
    cout << rabbit  << " 1st memory location \n" 
         << &rabbit << " 2nd memory location";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need somewhere physical to store the pointer itself.  It doesn't come "for free".

Comment: Would you say that `animal` holds both a string and a memory location? You could just as easily output `animal` and `&animal`, where the second output is a memory location. Does that mean `animal` "holds" a memory location?

Comment: Related, but from a different perspective: [Pointer in C++ Same variable have two different address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830640/)

Answer (score 4):

A pointer holds one memory address. `&rabbit` is the address of the `rabbit` variable itself.

Comment: It means even a pointer have memory address?

Comment: @yuiamanda Every variable has a memory address, even pointers. You need to store them somewhere, after all :-)

Comment: If so, rabbit is address of animal. and &rabbit is address of rabbit. I try to create another pointer to hold rabbit address. I get compile error.  `string *hold = &rabbit; cout << hold << " " << &rabbit;`

Comment: @yuiamanda The address of an `int` is an `int*`. The address of a `string` is a `string*`. Add an asterisk. The type of `rabbit` is `string *`, so its address is a `string **`.

Comment: @JaMiT Ow, each pointer link create level pointer. it determined by how many asteriks. okay, i understood.

Comment: `Every variable has a memory address` reference variables don't necessarily have a memory address (and there's no way to directly get the address in a case where it has).

Answer (score 0):

As when we declare pointer rabbit it will hold some space in the memory. And when we call `&rabbit` it will hold the address of rabbit.